# How can I combine similar tasks to reduce total workload?

Tags: google-app-engine

I use App Engine, but the following problem could very well occur in any server application:

My application uses memcache to cache both large (~50 KB) and small (~0.5 KB) JSON documents which aggregate information which is expensive to refresh from the datastore. These JSON documents can change often, but the changes are sparse in the document (i.e., one item out of hundreds may change at a time). Currently, the application invalidates an entire document if something changes, and then will lazily re-create it later when it needs it. However,  I want to move to a more efficient design which updates whatever particular value changed in the JSON document directly from the cache.

One particular concern is contention from multiple tasks / request handlers updating the same document, but I have ways to detect this issue and mitigate it. However, my main concern is that it's possible that there could be rapid changes to a set of documents within a small period of time coming from different request handlers, and I don't want to have to edit the JSON document in the cache separately for each one. For example, it's possible that 10 small changes affecting the same set of 20 documents of 50 KB each could be triggered in less than a minute.

So this is my problem: What would be an effective solution to combine these changes together? In my old solution, although it is expensive to re-create an entire document when a small item changes, the benefit at least is that it does it lazily when it needs it (which could be a while later). However, to update the JSON document with a small change seems to require that it be done immediately (not lazily). That is, unless I come up with a complex solution that lazily applies a set of changes to the document later on. I'm hoping for something efficient but not too complicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull queue. Everyone using GAE should watch this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AM0ZPO7-lcE

When a call comes in, update memcache and do an async_add to your task pull queue. You likely could run a process that will handle thousands of updates each minute without a lot of overhead (i.e. instance issues). Still have an issue should memcache get purged prior to your updates, but that it not too hard to work around. HTH. -stevep

Comment: Thanks. That video is great. I have been making plans to do more aggregation of large data sets, and pull queue would be great for that.